# Show game score in div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've been doing some searching about updating a div containing a scoreboard but I can't really get to the bottom of it. Is there any downside of using innerHTML, what other options are there?

What I'm trying to get is a score that updates every time the score changes, which at the moment is where the correct/incorrect alerts are as well.

Excerpt from the fiddle:

```
if(pick1 == pick2 && id1!=id2){
    alert('Correct');
    score += 100;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94jerdaw/Sr3Yp/

Answer (score 1):

Consider using jQuery to update the scoreboard's html:

```
$('.scoreboard').html(score);

pick1 = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with innerHTML or innerText, but you might want to look into frameworks like jQuery to do that.